# Sidebar not going full height of page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a side bar called column left. for some reason it does not go the full height of page when I have extra panels on view.

I use bootstrap with it as well with a fixed navbar at top.

Question: Why is it side bar "column left" not going full height what every page size is. What would be the best solution to solve it?

**Codepen preview**

**Code View** http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/bdaGro/

**Full View** http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/full/bdaGro/

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,vietnamese);

/* Global */
body {
    /*height: 100%;*/
    margin: 0;
    /*min-height: 100% !important;*/
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 70px;
    width: 100%;
}

#user-bar-chart {
    height: 300px;
}

#client-bar-chart {
    height: 300px;
}

a,
a:hover, 
a:focus {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}

tr:hover a.dashboard-user:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f044";
    font-size: 14px;
}

/* fix for bootstrap hidden and visible */
span.hidden-xs, span.hidden-sm, span.hidden-md, span.hidden-lg {
    display: inline;
}

/* Layout  */

.container-fluid {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#content {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* Column Left  */

#column-left {
    width: 50px;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    background-color: #515151;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}


#column-left + #content {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#column-left + #content + #footer {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #column-left {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: none;
    }

    #column-left + #content {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    #column-left + #content + #footer {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

}

/* Column Left Active */

#column-left.active {
    width: 235px;
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

#column-left.active {
    overflow: auto;
}

#column-left.active + #content {
    margin-left: 235px;
}

#column-left.active + #content + #footer {
    margin-left: 235px;
}

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

    #column-left.active + #content {
        position: relative;
        left: 235px;
    }

    #column-left.active + #content + #footer {
        position: relative;
        left: 235px;
    }

}

#column-left.active {
    width: 235px;
}

#column-left.active #menu li i {
    font-size: 14px;
}

#column-left.active #menu > li > a > span {
    display: inline;
}

#column-left.active #menu > li > ul {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    width: auto;
    visibility: visible;
}

/* Top Navbar */

.menu {
    background: #eeeeee none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

#button-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #6D6D6D;
}


@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 15px 7px;
    }
}

/* Sidebar Menu */

#menu, 
#menu ul, 
#menu li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#menu > li {
    position: relative;
}

#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #515151;
}

#menu li a i {
    font-size: 16px;
}

#menu > li > a {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    font-size: 14px;    
    padding-left: 13px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #585858;
}

#menu > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #444444;
}

#menu > li > a > span {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

#menu li li a {
    color: #9d9d9d;
}

#menu li li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #373737;
}

#menu li li a:before {
    content: "\f101";
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: margin ease 0.5s;   
}

#menu li li a:hover:before {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#menu > li.active > a {
    color: #DDDDDD;
    background: #373737;
}

#menu li.active li a {
    color: #C4C4C4;
}

#menu li li.active > a:last-child {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu li li.active a:last-child:before {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#menu > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 210px;
    background-color: #444444;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#menu li ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu > li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}

#menu li li a.parent:after, #column-left.active #menu > li a.parent:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f105";
    float: right;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

#menu li li.open > a.parent:after, #column-left.active #menu > li.open > a.parent:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f107";
    float: right;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

#menu li ul a {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#menu li li ul a {
    padding-left: 40px;
}

#menu li li li ul a {
    padding-left: 60px;
}

#menu li li li li ul a {
    padding-left: 80px;
}

/* Panels */
.panel {
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.panel .panel-heading {
    position: relative;
}
.panel-heading h3 i {
    margin-right: 8px;  
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.panel-heading i {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;   
}
.panel-heading h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Primary Panel */
.panel-primary {
    border: 1px solid #c3e4f6;
    border-top: 2px solid #5cb7e7;
}

.panel-primary .panel-heading {
    color: #1e91cf;
    border-color: #96d0f0;
    background: white;
}

/* Default Panel */
.panel-default {
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-top: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
}

.panel-default .panel-heading {
    color: #595959;
    border-color: #e8e8e8;
    background: #fcfcfc;
}

/* Info Panel */
.panel-info {
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-top: 2px solid #3c8dbc;
}

.panel-info .panel-heading {
    color: #595959;
    border-color: #e8e8e8;
    background: #fcfcfc;
}
```

Comment: The code previews have now been updated with @Slavenko Miljic answer and it's working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that adding `'position:fixed;'` to your `#column-left` should do the trick.

In that case no matter how large/long your content is, the sidebar will always remain at 100% height of viewport, fixed at the left side of the screen.

```
div#column-left {
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  background-color: #515151;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your body as `position: relative` if you want your left column to take the full height of your page. I would also explicitely set your column to take full height by removing your `min-height` and setting `top: 0; bottom:0;` on your column:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#column-left {
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #515151;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is actually 100% of the height of the viewport. (Not 100% of the page length).
What you can do:

1. `#column-left { position: fixed; }`
2. use `display: table-cell` on `#column-left` and `#content`
3. use flexbox (depending on if you have to support old browsers)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it matters that it follows when you scroll the page, but you could make it `position:fixed`.

Perhaps that's an easy fix for you